# Radius of Finite Convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, divergent-series

I am trying to solve a problem where I have to find the radius of finite convergence [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRKKN.png). I believe that I solved the problem correctly, receiving an answer of 1. However, I was informed that this was incorrect but I am not sure why.

My process involved using the ratio test and ultimately received:

(x+2) lim n/(n+1) which goes to 1

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: UPDATE: I believe that I may have figured out where I went wrong and should have received (n/(n+1))^n which goes to 1/e. If anyone sees this am I correct in my correction or am I still off?

Comment: The ratio is calculated wrong. You have missed $n^n/(n+1)^{n+1}$.

Comment: yes, so does the +1 portion of n+1 cancel with the remaining n+1 in the numerator that originated from (n+1)! leading to the answer that I found in my update or is my assumption wrong?

Comment: Now you are on track.

Comment: And then this will give me that the interval of convergence is from 1/e - 2 to -1/e - 2 correct? Thank you for your help

Comment: Seems correct now. ${{{{}}}}$

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Ratio Test, you have
$$
\begin{split}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\dfrac{\dfrac{(n+1)!(x+2)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{n+1}}}{\dfrac{n!(x+2)^n}{n^n}} \right|&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\dfrac{(n+1)!(x+2)^{n+1}n^n}{n!(x+2)^n(n+1)^{n+1}} \right| \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \dfrac{(n+1)(x+2)n^n}{(n+1)(n+1)^n} \right| \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \dfrac{(x+2)n^n}{(n+1)^n} \right| \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left|(x+2) \; \left( \dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)^n \right| \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left|(x+2) \; \left( \dfrac{n+1}{n}\right)^{-n} \right| \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left|(x+2) \; \left( 1+ \dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{-n} \right| \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left|(x+2) \; \left(\left( 1+ \dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\right)^{-1} \right| \\
&= |x+2| \cdot e^{-1},
\end{split}
$$
which is what you found. The trick with these harder Ratio Test problems is working slowly and being careful with the Algebra.